# Does GTK+ have runtime dependency

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I am trying to follow the GTK+ hello world tutorial [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html). I compiled the code to executable and tried to run it. Then i got an error which said failed to load a particular package. I installed the package and ran the executable. Now, the executable ran perfectly as expected. Does this mean GTK+ has runtime dependencies on these modules?

So, should the system in which my executable runs have GTK+ installed ?

Can't my executable be a standalone program?

Comment: `Can't my executable be a standalone program?` Static linking.

Answer (score 1):

In modern system, almost any program has 'dependencies'. These libraries help make executables smaller by sharing parts with other executables. Even a small test C program needs the C library to execute. Do a

```
ldd <your executable>
```

to see the list of libraries on which your executable depends.

There is a way to avoid this - by linking statically. In this case all dependencies will be included in the executable. But you will probably have to install the static version of the libraries to get there, and you will have huge executables. (note that this is a somewhat simplified explanation)

Also note that the request for a gtk-dev or gtk-devel package is not a run-time dependency.

Answer (score 1):

GTK+ is a library, which means that you need to ship the library's shared objects with your executable. GTK+ itself has its own dependencies, which means that you have a set of libraries you need to ship with your executable — unless you know that the target platform has GTK+ and its dependencies already available. Most applications on Linux work on this assumption, whereas other platforms, like Windows and MacOS, cannot.

There's the option of statically linking your binary with GTK+, but GTK+ and some of its dependencies may still have run-time loadable modules that will require shipping alongside your binary. The static linking option is also not well tested.

It is vastly preferable to build your application with the set of depencies, and then ship the whole thing with an installer, or as an archive.